# How do I look for “ and ” in php using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've been using `"/x{201C}/u"` and `"/x{201D}/u"` to match them, but there's no result.

Am I doing something wrong??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been using `"/x{201C}/u"` and `"/x{201D}/u"` to match them, but there's no result.

You need to type `"/\x{201C}/u"` and `"/\x{201D}/u"`

Answer (score 0):

Oh.. shoot! that's a stupid question... '|“|' and "|”|" works!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

\x8c and \x9d

Those have worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

if your requirement is that simple as just finding double quotes, just use PHP's string methods

```
$str='mystring_with_"_blah';
if ( strpos($str,'"') !==FALSE){
    print "Found double quotes\n";
}
```